# Updating MySQL using a form my code is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do something really simple here. All I want to do is to update information in MySQL
Here is the code below for the form.

```
 <?php
 $host=""; // Host name 
 $username=""; // Mysql username 
 $password=""; // Mysql password 
 $db_name=""; // Database name 
 $tbl_name=""; // Table name 

 // Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 // get value of id that sent from address bar
 $dj=$_GET['dj'];

 // Retrieve data from database 
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE dj='$dj'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
 ?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update The information for the Now PlayingProgram.</strong>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email2</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $rows['name']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="email2" type="text" id="email2" value="<?php echo $rows['email2']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Twitter</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Twitter2</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Avatar</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="twitter" type="text" id="twitter" value="<?php echo $rows['twitter']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="twitter2" type="text" id="twitter2" value="<?php echo $rows['twitter2']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="avatar" type="text" id="avatar" value="<?php echo $rows['avatar']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Facebook</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Facebook2</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Type</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="facebook" type="text" id="facebook" value="<?php echo $rows['facebook']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="facebook2" type="text" id="facebook2" value="<?php echo $rows['facebook2']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="type" type="text" id="type" value="<?php echo $rows['type']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Alias1</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Alias2</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Alias3</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="alias1" type="text" id="alias1" value="<?php echo $rows['alias1']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="alias2" type="text" id="alias2" value="<?php echo $rows['alias2']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="alias3" type="text" id="alias3" value="<?php echo $rows['alias3']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
 <td colspan="3" align="center"><strong>Request Line</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3" align="center">
 <input name="address" type="text" id="address" value="<?php echo $rows['address']; ?>" size="65">
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>
 <input name="dj" type="hidden" id="dj" value="<?php echo $rows['dj']; ?>">
 </td>
 <td align="center">
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
 </form>
 </tr>
 </table>
  <?php
 // close connection 
 mysql_close();
 ?>
```

Now what I want to be able to do is to edit the information in the database that is currently displayed in the form. (the form is displaying the correct info from mysql)
If i wanted to change lets say the email2 i would just do so in the field and then click submit. Well my issue is that when I do that, all i get is ERROR.

So lets take a look at my update_ac.php
code is below:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE currentdj SET  name='$name',
                        email='$email',
                        email2='$email2',                           
                        twitter='$twitter',
                        twitter2='$twitter2',
                        avatar='$avatar',                           
                        facebook='$facebook',
                        facebook2='$facebook2',
                        type='$type',
                        alias1='$alias1',
                        alias2='$alias2',
                        alias3='$alias3',
                        address='$address'                          
                        WHERE dj='$dj'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

I would like to know if I am just having a syntax or even a spelling issue here!
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: all i get is simply ERROR, thats because of the:
     else {
     echo "ERROR";
     }
At the end of my update_ac.php

Comment: you forgot to close the `email='$email` with single quote.

Comment: yes i see that but it still does not solve my issue.

Comment: ok i fixed the ERROR issue, by delted the last "," after address='$address'  
But now still the information is not being updated in the database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update_ac.php file , you haven't used `$_POST[]` variable to retrieve values from your form. As a result no values are being inserted in the database and hence the error.

Put this code before the update query statement where you have $sql="UPDATE.....

```
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $email2=$_POST['email2'];                          
 $twitter=$_POST['twitter'];
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

In `UPDATE` query single quotes is not closed for `email` field `email='$email,`

```
"UPDATE currentdj SET  name='$name',
                        email='$email',    //Add THE MISSING SINGLE QUOTE HERE
                        email2='$email2',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, before where `,`(`address='$address', WHERE dj='$dj'";`) should not come

```
$sql="UPDATE currentdj SET  name='$name',
                        email='$email',
                        email2='$email2',                           
                        twitter='$twitter',
                        twitter2='$twitter2',
                        avatar='$avatar',                           
                        facebook='$facebook',
                        facebook2='$facebook2',
                        type='$type',
                        alias1='$alias1',
                        alias2='$alias2',
                        alias3='$alias3',
                        address='$address'                        
                        WHERE dj='$dj'";
```

Comment: ok well i now longer get the error, but now what is odd is the info is not being updated in mysql

Comment: try to echo your query, see what you are getting?